# 2 Different functors $T: \mathbf{Grp} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$

Tags: category-theory

I'm relatively new to category theory, and I am to find to different functors on the category of groups $ T_1, T_2: \mathbf{Grp} \longrightarrow \mathbf{Grp}$ such that $T_1(G)=T_2(G)= G$ for all $G \in \mathbf{Grp}$. Now one is obviously the identity functor, I.e. $T_1 f = f$ for all homomorphisms $f$. Now with the second one, we know that $T_2(\mathrm{Id}_G) = \mathrm{Id}_{T_2(G)} = \mathrm{Id}_{G}$, so $T_2$ basically preserves all isomorphisms. How can we "twist" the functor such that it differs on other homomorphisms from $T_1$? Is this the right approach or did I perhaps completely misunderstand the question?

Comment: Ok. If we take Tf = e to be the constant arrow (I.e. (Tf)x = e for all x in G for all G), then if we take f: S2 -> S3 to be the inclusion map, and g:S3 -> S2 the sign map (S2, S3 symmetric groups respectively), we have T(fg) = T(Id) = Id but T(f)T(g) = ee = e which is not the identity

Comment: I mean T(gf) and T(g)T(f) of course

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4276/two-functors-from-grp-to-grp) on MathOverflow.